# HTML input alignment

Tags: html, css

Busy on a game involving buttons. Having 2 questions about problems I stumbled upon.

### Code:

```css
input {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="button"  value="foo">
    <input type="button"  value="">
    <input type="button"  value="">
      <br/>
    <input type="button"  value="">
    <input type="button"  value="">
    <input type="button"  value="">
      <br/>
    <input type="button"  value="">
    <input type="button"  value="">
    <input type="button"  value="">

  </body>
</html>
```

### Questions:

1. Why do the button misalign when I put in a value in the the button? Dev tools also says it still the same size (50px 50px) so why does it change position?
2. How can I style the CSS to have zero distance bewteen the buttons (in other words: the borders of the buttons touch). I already tried to set padding/margin of html/body/input but none of these seems to work.

Comment: This is a good question upvote! and try it first

Comment: might be better, if you group them (under three divs) and apply float:left and make sure to clear each float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why are the buttons with text being pushed down?

So there's a bit at play here. Text and inline elements vertically-align to the *baseline* by default. The baseline is a value determined by the `line-height` of the element, though an element without a `line-height` will determine a "reasonable" value<sup>[1]</sup> - in the case of an empty element, this will be 0. However when you add text, the element is then given a `line-height` and moved down by that amount.<sup>[2]</sup>

A simple solution is to force the inputs to render with the same alignment, text or not, by applying `vertical-align: top`.

---

### Why is there space between the buttons?

*Inline* elements (and `inline-block` elements like your inputs) will naturally align side-by-side, however they behave similarly to text<sup>[3]</sup>. Much like if you were to put a line-break between two letters in your HTML, a line-break between `inline` elements will add a single space between them.

Hypothetically, if you were to put all of your inputs on one line (without spaces), it would solve your issue:

```html
<input type="button" value="these" /><input type="button" value="are" /><input type="button" value="touching" />

<br><br>

<input type="button" value="these" />
<input type="button" value="are" />
<input type="button" value="not" />
```

**Though I don't suggest that method** - it's merely for demonstration purposes.

---

### So what's the solution?

Well, you have some options. Choose the one that you think would work best for you.

**Solution 1:** Wrap the inputs in a container and apply `font-size: 0` to it. The spaces will still be there, but the `font-size: 0` ensures they aren't visible.

```css
input {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container {
font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" value="foo">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** Bypass the triviality of `inline` elements and make use of `display: block` with [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

```css
input {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.row {display: block;}

.row::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="button" value="foo">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
```

**Solution 3:** Use a more modern approach, like [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
input {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" value="foo">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
```

---

**Sources**

<sup>1: [*"**normal:** Tells user agents to set the computed value to a "reasonable" value*"](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)</sup>

<sup>2: [*"For inline non-replaced elements, the box used for alignment is the box whose height is the 'line-height'.*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)</sup>

<sup>3: [*"Inline-level elements generate inline-level boxes, which are boxes that participate in an inline formatting context."*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#inline-boxes)</sup>

Comment: @Santi, can you give me more explain？I'm trying to understand your answer. In my mind, if I set vertical-align:*, they should have some position, but why fewer vertical-align: method works

Comment: @Carson `vertical-align` specifies the alignment of an item or text *within its container*, and it only works on `inline` and `table` elements. Setting `vertical-align` on something like a `<div>` will not work ,as a `<div>` is a `block` element. I've edited my answer to provide alternative solutions as well as a bit more explanation. You can read more about `vertical-align` (and see some helpful visualizations) [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Comment: @Santi I've read your link and I know it only works inline or table element, my question is why `vertical-align: baseline` not works. English is not my mother language, maybe I didn't understand your words

Answer (score 1):

*"Why do the button misalign when I put in a value in the the button?"*

The default value for elements with text content `vertical-align` is a `baseline`, so you need to specify it (in my case I use `vertical-align: middle`).

"*How can I style the CSS to have zero distance bewteen the buttons (in other words: the borders of the buttons touch)*"

I followed a little hacky way and set a negative `margin-left` value to get buttons without space between them. I have selected specific items using `input:nth-child(2n)` and `input:nth-child(4n - 1)` selectors and gave `margin-left: -4px;` to them.

Here is my solution:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  vertical-align: middle
}

input:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: -4px;
}

input:nth-child(4n - 1) {
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

  <input type="button"  value="foo">
  <input type="button"  value="">
  <input type="button"  value="">
    <br/>
  <input type="button"  value="">
  <input type="button"  value="">
  <input type="button"  value="">
    <br/>
  <input type="button"  value="">
  <input type="button"  value="">
  <input type="button"  value="">

  </body>
</html>
```

Feel free to ask, if anything isn't clear!

Comment: I'll add an explanation in few minutes

Comment: @j08691, I have added an explanation

Comment: @j08691 Nope - I did ;) I upvoted instead once the explanation was added.

Answer (score 0):

For question two, you can try the border-spacing method.

For example:

```
input {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) and [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) only apply to `table` and `inline-table` elements.